# "C'était encore à qui troublerait l'autre": how translate?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

This is a passage from Philippe Sollers' literary story 'Le Défi' (1956):

> Et pourtant par ce dernier geste qui était pour elle comme pour moi la suprême tentation, j'étais sûr qu'elle me voulait défier, morte, de mon insensibilité. C'était encore à qui troublerait l'autre.

I am wondering how you would translate the last sentence into English. What does 'c'était' refer to? And what is the significance of the 'à'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« C'était à qui +conditionnel » is a set phrase indicating that multiple people are performing some action very often. It is always an intensifier. It often suggests competition, but not always: the expression can also be used if the people are performing the action independently, but it looks externally like they're competing. The second clause can often include a comparative which indicates the goal of the (actual or apparent) competition.

> Le brouhaha s'amplifiait de minute en minute. C'était à qui crierait le plus fort.   (People are shouting and the volume is escalating because they're shouting over each other.)
> Depuis le changement de règlement, les plaintes se multipliaient. C'était à qui râlerait le plus.   (Many people are independently complaining loudly about the new regulation.)

So “*C'était à qui troublerait l'autre*” indicates that the narrator and the woman are used to repeatedly troubling each other. Her death appears to be one more step, an ultimate escalation.

This is a literary construct. It is uncommon, but not unheard of, in modern non-literary usage. When there is escalation, a more colloquial turn of phrase with a broadly similar meaning is “*… plus les uns que les autres*” (lit. “each one more than the others”), e.g. “*ils criaient tous plus fort les uns que les autres*”. Though it wouldn't work in Soller's story, besides being too colloquial, because there is no more escalation at this point.

Comment: I would say that brouhaha bit is: Whoever shouted the loudest would be heard. And the other: Whoever complained the most would be heard. But, that obviously does not work for the Soller's story.

Comment: [The winner takes it all](https://youtu.be/92cwKCU8Z5c)... ;)

Answer (score 4):

***C'était*** has no *antécédent*, it refers to nothing.

It is a literary turn of phrase that means both of them were once again at the same time willing to trouble the other, kind of competing to do it.

We use the same ***c'était*** and ***à*** in this sentence:

> ***C'était** encore **à** toi de jouer*: It was still your turn to play.

Note that ***c'est à** quelqu'un **de*** doesn't necessarily translates to "**it's up to** someone **to**". The English idiom implies the person has a choice while the French one doesn't.

> *C'est à toi de choisir/décider*: "It's up to you".

> *C'est à toi de tirer*: "It's your turn to shoot", not "it's up to you to shoot".

Comment: No, it's up to does not imply any choice. It depends on the verb that follows. C'est à toi de choisir/décider: "It's up to you **to choose or decide**". It depends on the context.

Comment: @Lambie *Up to one* doesn't need to be followed by a verb in the first place. There is no verb in my example and it is not needed. A decision is always a choice, etymologically at least.

Comment: You misunderstand what I am **saying**.  The translation depends on the verb **in French that follows in the expression**.  It is not about "up to one".

Comment: @Lambie I'm talking about *up to one* in my reply and it implies a choice is present. If you want to say the verb that follows *c'est à X de* plays a role to select the best translation in English, then of course it does. My examples already show it.

Comment: Lambie is correct. In the UK and Australia, at least, it's common to say "It's up to you" when it's simply the other person's turn. For example, if I were playing cards and John, whose turn to play it is, is distracted, I might say, "It's up to you, John".

Comment: @HarryAudus Thanks for the comment. I'm surprised about it because I never heard *up to you* used to mean anything else than *It's your responsibility*. I still think *It's your responsibility* is the most usual meaning so would be a poor translation of *c'est à toi* for at least being ambiguous.

Comment: @HarryAudus To clarify what I mean, I understand that you can also say *It's up to you to play* in a game where there is no mandatory sequence of play while *C'est à toi de jouer* implies there is one.

Comment: It's up to someone is not necessarily about responsibility at all.

Comment: @Lambie Granted, not always a responsibility but either a responsibility or a choice. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-up-to-somebody Would you translate *a ti te toca* by *it's up to you*?

Comment: Spanish has nothing at all to do with this.

Comment: @Lambie I consider *te toca de* to be a very close translation of *c'est à toi de*. As you happen to speak Spanish, I was wondering if you consider *te toca (de)* to match *it's up to you (to)*. If you don't want to answer, nevermind.

Comment: te toca a ti can mean many things. Such as: it's your turn. Te toca a ti fregar [hoy]. It's your turn to do the dishes. But C'est à toi de faire la vaisselle. But, "Go or don't go, it's up to you, in Spanish would be:  Irte o no, tú decides. in French, Y aller ou pas, c'est à toi de décider.

Comment: @Lambie So would you say *It's up to you to do the dishes* in the first case like I believe Harry would?

Comment: When I translated the OP's question: to be up to means: the outcome would still depend on upsets whom.

Comment: Un exemple parfait de prison morpho-syntaxique à mon avis. Peut-être un truc avec _race_ ou _war_ avec un verbe et _still_ le tout se terminant par _on_. _The race for annoyance was still on_, un truc du genre mais plus idiomatique...

Comment: @jilliagre. Well, it's one of those bizarre aspects of English where a word or a phrase, in this case, cam mean two quite opposite things, depending on context, and I don't mean grammatical context but the actual situation. (Like, famously, the word "cleave" can mean to stick to or to split apart.)

Comment: @jilliagre. ... "It's up to you [to do it]" can mean either "You can [do it] if you want to" (with no expectations), or (as you said) "You have an obligation [to do it]". I suppose it could also mean both things at the same time, depending on the actual context - you ought to do it but you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

être à quelqu'un here means: to be up to someone, but can also be other things. Read on.

C'était is impersonal (in French: **une expression impersonnelle**), what we call a dummy subject in English. As in: C'était vraiment amusant. It was very amusing.

- It was still up to who would upset the other.
- It would still boil down to who would upset the other.

In other words, in this disagreeable situation between these lovers, "it was still up to" means: it would still boil down to who would upset the other.  Of the two, the one who manages to upset the other will win out.